# How do I parse a String to get the decimal and a word with a dot properly?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, delimiter

How do I differentiate the difference in finding a decimal but at the same time ignoring it if it is a period?

For example, assume Scanner

```
String s = "2015. 3.50 please";
```

When I use the function `scanner.hasNextFloat()`, how do I ignore *Hi.*?

I am only scanning 1 line. I need to identify whether a word is string, integer, or float. My final result should look something like this:

```
This is a String: 2015.
This is a float: 3.50
This is a String: please
```

But in my conditions when I use `scanner.hasNextFloat();` it identifies *2015.* as a float.

Comment: Are you scanning ONLY this line?  Or are you generically reading text into your application and trying to interpret if it sees numbers or words?

Comment: I am only scanning 1 line. I need to identify whether a word is string, integer, or float. 
My final result should look something like this.
"This is a String: Hi."
"This is a float: 3.50"
"This is a String: please"
But in my conditions when i use scanner.hasNextFloat(); it identifies Hi. as a float

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you might use a regular expression. One or more digits, followed by a literal dot and then two digits. Something like

```
String s = "Hi. 3.50 please";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(\\d+\\.\\d{2}).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
Float amt = null;
if (m.matches()) {
    amt = Float.parseFloat(m.group(1));
}
System.out.printf("Ammount: %.2f%n", amt);
```

Output is

```
Ammount: 3.50
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean java, as javascript doesn't have a Scanner.

```
    String s = "Hi. 3.50 please";

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.println("This is an int: " + scanner.next());
        } else if (scanner.hasNextFloat()){
            System.out.println("This is a float: " + scanner.next());
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is a String: " + scanner.next());
        }

    }
```

Output:

```
This is a String: Hi.
This is a float: 3.50
This is a String: please
```

So, what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i worded the question confusingly. 
I need to display "Hi" as a string but 3.50 as a float, so how do I not ignore it.

Comment: What does that mean? What if it's an integer?  I don't get what you mean by period.  You need a better example.

Comment: Sorry, i meant it identifies Hi. as a float

Comment: What if String s = "123. 3.50 please";

Comment: Why don't you run my code and find out?  For me it shows 123. as a float but only because of the decimal.  If you put in "555 123. 3.50" it will interpret it as int, float, float.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to match the numbers

```
    String[] str = { " Hi, My age is 12", "I have 30$", "Eclipse version 4.2" };
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\s+([0-9.]+).*");
    for (String string : str) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(string);
        System.out.println("Count " + m.groupCount());
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.group(1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

`Count 1
12 
Count 1
30 
Count 1
4.2`

If numbers can in power of `e` or `E`, add `[0-9.eE]` in the pattern String